# Submitting one value of the Hidden input in the current row clicked

Tags: php, form-submit, hidden-field

How to pass one value of the current row of multiple hidden input in PHP. I have the following code:

```
foreach($portfolio as $portfolio){
echo  "<tr class ='table-comments'>";
echo  "<td>".$portfolio['portfolio_title']."</td>";
echo  "<td class = 'comment-content'>".$portfolio['portfolio_client']."</td>";
echo  "<td><a target = '_blank' href = ".$portfolio['portfolio_link'].">".$portfolio['portfolio_link']."</a></td>";
echo  "<td>";
echo  "<input type='hidden' name='portfolio_id' value='" . $portfolio['portfolio_id'] . "' />";
echo "<input type = 'submit'  value = 'Edit'>";
echo "<input type = 'submit' value = 'Move to Trash' class = 'action-button'>";
echo  "</td>";
echo  "</tr>";
}
```

I also have submit button each row that triggers the form. When I click the submit button, it submits all the value of the row of the hidden input. I only want the clicked button row value.

URL is like this:

`/portfolio?portfolio_id=1&portfolio_id=2&portfolio_id=3&portfolio_id=4` and so on

I only want

```
/portfolio?portfolio_id=3
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'll check that function first. Is it going to be placed in the receiving page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a new form for each row...

```
<form method="get">

</form>
```

Like this:

```
foreach($portfolio as $portfolio){

    echo  "<tr class ='table-comments'>";
    echo  "<td>".$portfolio['portfolio_title']."</td>";
    echo  "<td class = 'comment-content'>".$portfolio['portfolio_client']."</td>";
    echo  "<td><a target = '_blank' href = ".$portfolio['portfolio_link'].">".$portfolio['portfolio_link']."</a></td>";
    echo  "<td>";
    echo '<form method="get">';
    echo  "<input type='hidden' name='portfolio_id' value='" . $portfolio['portfolio_id'] . "' />";
    echo "<input type = 'submit'  value = 'Edit'>";
    echo "<input type = 'submit' value = 'Move to Trash' class = 'action-button'>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo  "</td>";
    echo  "</tr>";

}
```

Comment: do you mean I'll put the form tag inside the foreach? I have thousands of records BTW

Comment: I'll give it a try first

Comment: Yeah, look at the example I provided

Comment: wow, that's cool. But how's that? why it don't submit one value in a current row when the submit button was clicked?

Comment: Because if you don't group them with <form>, it will submit all the values on the page.

Comment: I thought It would be too redundant or messy or whatever you call that if you have too many forms in a repeating rows. haha (y)

Comment: @ajdeguzman if this answer helped you solve your problem, don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The form tag should be included on the looping.

change this

```
foreach ($portfolio as $portfolio) {
    echo  "<tr class ='table-comments'>";
    echo  "<td>".$portfolio['portfolio_title']."</td>";
    echo  "<td class = 'comment-content'>".$portfolio['portfolio_client']."</td>";
    echo  "<td><a target = '_blank' href = ".$portfolio['portfolio_link'].">".$portfolio['portfolio_link']."</a></td>";
    echo  "<td>";
    echo  "<input type='hidden' name='portfolio_id' value='" . $portfolio['portfolio_id'] . "' />";
    echo "<input type = 'submit'  value = 'Edit'>";
    echo "<input type = 'submit' value = 'Move to Trash' class = 'action-button'>";
    echo  "</td>";
    echo  "</tr>";
}
```

to:

```
foreach ($portfolio as $portfolio) {
    echo  "<tr class ='table-comments'>";
    echo  "<td>".$portfolio['portfolio_title']."</td>";
    echo  "<td class = 'comment-content'>".$portfolio['portfolio_client']."</td>";
    echo  "<td><a target = '_blank' href = ".$portfolio['portfolio_link'].">".$portfolio['portfolio_link']."</a></td>";
    echo  "<td>";
    echo  "<form action='process.php' method='get'>";
    echo  "<input type='hidden' name='portfolio_id' value='" . $portfolio['portfolio_id'] . "' />";
    echo "<input type = 'submit'  value = 'Edit'>";
    echo "<input type = 'submit' value = 'Move to Trash' class = 'action-button'>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo  "</td>";
    echo  "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: This won't work, the action attribute should be empty or not present, how do you he has a process.php file...

Comment: pick this as an answer. thans.

Comment: process.php is only an example if you will process it to other page. I have a question for you, is it only 1 hidden value that is need in a form?

Answer (score 0):

If all you're submitting is that ID, and you're using `GET` instead of `POST` you might as well not even use forms and use links instead. You can still style a link to look like a button if you want, but using a link would make a lot more sense semantically. Remove the hidden input, and have each link have the URL you want.